# Help prove a matrix equality

Tags: matrices, inverse

Given

- an $M\times 1$ vector $\mathbf{a}$ with norm $\| \mathbf{a} \|=\sqrt{M}$
- an invertible, Hermitian and Toeplitz matrix $\mathbf{R}$
- an $M \times (M-1)$ matrix $\mathbf{C}_n$ whose rank is $M-1$
- vector $\mathbf{a}$ is orthogonal to each column of $\mathbf{C}_n$

I'm trying to prove the following equality

$$\frac{1}{M}\left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{C}_n \left(\mathbf{C}_n^H\mathbf{R}\mathbf{C}_n \right)^{-1}\mathbf{C}_n^H\mathbf{R} \right) \mathbf{a}=\frac{\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}}{\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @EDX I don't know where to start:(

Comment: Mutliply the result by RHS's denominator, use associativity of matrix's product and play with orthogonality, Hermitian character of your matrixes

Comment: @EDX I am sorry but I can't follow your idea. Can you give the derivation?

Comment: @user1551 Yes, you are right. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Pi=I-C_n(C_n^HRC_n)^{-1}C_n^HR$ is an idempotent matrix that maps $C_n$ to zero and leaves $R^{-1}a$ unchanged. Hence it is a rank-one projection onto the linear span of $R^{-1}a$.

Now observe that $R^{-1}a$ and $a^H$ are respectively the right and left eigenvectors of $\Pi$ corresponding to the unit eigenvalue. Therefore $\Pi=cR^{-1}aa^H$ for some scalar $c$. As the rank and trace of a projection matrix coincide, we have $\operatorname{tr}(\Pi)=1$. Hence $c=\frac{1}{a^HR^{-1}a}$ and
$$
\Pi=\frac{R^{-1}aa^H}{a^HR^{-1}a}.
$$
Consequently, $\frac{1}{M}\Pi a=\frac{R^{-1}a}{a^HR^{-1}a}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW, is it possible to get the RHS of the equation directly from the LHS, i.e., if the purpose is to find the value of $\frac{1}{M}\left[\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{C}_n(\mathbf{C}_n^H\mathbf{R}\mathbf{C}_n)^{-1}\mathbf{C}_n^H\mathbf{R} \right]\mathbf{a}$?

Comment: yeah, that's excellent. I think both of your solutions are good and should be preserved.

Comment: @ecook No. I will only keep the current solution. The old one needs $R$ to be Hermitian, but as the current answer shows, this assumption is unnecessary.